# Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic and maps $|z|<1$ onto the $n$-times covered disk $|w|<1$. Show it's rational with denominator degree $\leq n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic and maps $|z|<1$ onto the $n$-times covered disk $|w|<1$ (i.e. each $f(z)$ has $n$ preimages). Show it's rational with denominator degree $\leq n$.

I've seen this problem in multiple places but have never seen a solution. If we include multiplicity, the function
$$
h(z) = z^n
$$
seems to satisfy our requirements. If we use the automorphisms of the unit disk to generalize,
$$
g(z) = \frac{z-a}{\overline a z - 1}
$$
gives us a solution if $n=1$. Intuitively, the function
$$
f(z) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{z-a_i}{\overline{a_i} z - 1} \right)^i
$$
seems to satisfy the requirements for any $n$ since it is rational and the denominator has degree less than or equal to $n$.

However, I have been unsuccessful in proving that any such $f$ must be of this form.

Any thoughts towards a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we show that $f$ is a proper map: If $|z_k|\to1$ then $|f(z_k)|\to1$. Suppose not. Then there is a sequence $z_k$ with $|z_k|\to1$ and $f(z_k)\to w$, where $|w|<1$. Say the preimage of $w$ is $(p_1,\dots,p_n)$.

The Open Mapping Theorem shows that there exist $\delta>0$, $r\in(0,1)$, and open sets $O_1,\dots,O_n$ such that the preimage of $D(w,\delta)$ is exactly $\bigcup_{k=1}^nO_k$, and such that $O_k\subset D(0,r)$ for every $k$. This gives a contradiction, since $|z_j|\to1$ and $f(z_j)\in D(w,\delta)$ for large $j$.

There's probably a more elegant way to say that. Anyway, now we're done. Say the preimage of $0$ is $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, and let $$B(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k-z}{1-\overline a_kz}$$(that's $B$ for *Blaschke product*). Let $$g=f/B.$$Then $g$ is holomorphic in the disk, $g$ has no zero, and $|g(z)|\to1$ as $|z|\to1$; anyone reading this can see how to show that implies $g$ is constant.

Comment: Wow this is very nice. I'm not familiar with the Blaschke product. In any case, it seems like the key to the proof that I was missing is the Open Mapping Theorem.

Comment: What is the general definition of a "proper map"? I also haven't seen this term before, not even in a book like Ahlfors.

Comment: @mathjacks In general $f$ iis proper if $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K$.