# if $g$ is analytic on the open disk, is nonzero, and if $|g(z)| \to 1$ as $|z| \to 1$, then $g$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that If $g$ is analytic on the open disk, is nonzero, and if $|g(z)| \to 1$ as $|z| \to 1$, then $g$ is constant. I want to apply the maximum principle and the minimum principle to conclude that the modulus is constant. I think that this would be possible if I could extend the domain to the closed disk as I would conclude that the maximum and minimum values of $g$ both have modulus 1. However, I do not know if I can/how to extend the definition of $g$ to the boundary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what it is worth, this fact is mentioned in the answer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774911/suppose-fz-is-analytic-and-maps-z1-onto-the-n-times-covered-disk-w/1774931#1774931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M_r=\max_{|z| \le r}|g(z)|$ when $0<r<1$. By maximum modulus $M_r$ is increasing and by the hypothesis $M_r \to 1$ as $r \to 1$. So $\sup_{|z|<1}|g(z)|=\sup_{0<r<1}M_r=\lim_{r\to 1}M_r=1$.

Applying the same reasoning to $\frac{1}{g}$ we get that $\inf_{|z|<1}|g(z)| =1$, so $|g(z)|=1$ in the open unit disc, so $g$ constant of modulus one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just what I needed.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Answer (score 1):

Some different answer that might be considered as cheating:

Since $g$ is analytic and nonzero in the open unit disk $\Delta$, the function $h(z)=\log|g(z)|$ is harmonic in $\Delta$. The condition $\lim_{|z|\to1}|g(z)|=1$ means we can extend $h$ to a continuous function on $\bar{\Delta}$ that is harmonic in $\Delta$ and also satisfies $h(z)=0$ for every $|z|=1$. From the uniqueness of the solution to the [Dirichlet problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletProblem.html) on the unit disk it follows that necessarily $h$ is identically zero and hence $g$ is of constant modulus, giving the desired result.

Regards!